# How to build all product flavors from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

I have many flavors in gradle file :

```
      def _versionName = "1.19"
      def _applicationId = "com.site.app"
      productFlavors {
        CafebazarPro {
            applicationId "${_applicationId}"
            versionName "${_versionName}" +"-Cafebazar-Pro"
       }


        CafebazarInPurchase {
            applicationId "${_applicationId}.inpurchase"
            versionName "${_versionName}" +"-Cafebazar-InPurchase"
         }

        //-------------------------------------------

        Cando {
            applicationId ${_applicationId}"
            versionName  "${_versionName}" +"-Cando-Pro"
        }

        //-------------------------------------------

        Myket {
            applicationId "${_applicationId}"
            versionName  "${_versionName}" +"-Myket-Pro"
        }

        //-----------------------------------------

        IranApps {
            applicationId "${_applicationId}"
            versionName  "${_versionName}" +"-IranApps-Pro"
        }
     }
```

How to build automatically all flavors ? not select and build one by one .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Cmd and run this command :

> gradlew tasks

```
Build tasks
-----------
assemble - Assembles all variants of all applications and secondary packages.
assembleAndroidTest - Assembles all the Test applications.
assembleDebug - Assembles all Debug builds.
assembleRelease - Assembles all Release builds.
build - Assembles and tests this project.
buildDependents - Assembles and tests this project and all projects that depend on it.
buildNeeded - Assembles and tests this project and all projects it depends on.
classes - Assembles main classes.
clean - Deletes the build directory.
compileDebugAndroidTestSources
compileDebugSources
compileDebugUnitTestSources
compileReleaseSources
compileReleaseUnitTestSources
jar - Assembles a jar archive containing the main classes.
mockableAndroidJar - Creates a version of android.jar that's suitable for unit tests.
testClasses - Assembles test classes.

Build Setup tasks
-----------------
init - Initializes a new Gradle build. [incubating]
wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files. [incubating]

Documentation tasks
-------------------
javadoc - Generates Javadoc API documentation for the main source code.

Help tasks
----------
buildEnvironment - Displays all buildscript dependencies declared in root project 'src'.
components - Displays the components produced by root project 'src'. [incubating]
dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project 'src'.
dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependency in root project 'src'.
help - Displays a help message.
model - Displays the configuration model of root project 'src'. [incubating]
projects - Displays the sub-projects of root project 'src'.
properties - Displays the properties of root project 'src'.
tasks - Displays the tasks runnable from root project 'src' (some of the displayed tasks may belong to subprojects).

Install tasks
-------------
installDebug - Installs the Debug build.
installDebugAndroidTest - Installs the android (on device) tests for the Debug build.
uninstallAll - Uninstall all applications.
uninstallDebug - Uninstalls the Debug build.
uninstallDebugAndroidTest - Uninstalls the android (on device) tests for the Debug build.
uninstallRelease - Uninstalls the Release build.

Verification tasks
------------------
check - Runs all checks.
connectedAndroidTest - Installs and runs instrumentation tests for all flavors on connected devices.
connectedCheck - Runs all device checks on currently connected devices.
connectedDebugAndroidTest - Installs and runs the tests for debug on connected devices.
deviceAndroidTest - Installs and runs instrumentation tests using all Device Providers.
deviceCheck - Runs all device checks using Device Providers and Test Servers.
lint - Runs lint on all variants.
lintDebug - Runs lint on the Debug build.
lintRelease - Runs lint on the Release build.
test - Run unit tests for all variants.
testDebugUnitTest - Run unit tests for the debug build.
testReleaseUnitTest - Run unit tests for the release build.

Other tasks
-----------
clean
jarDebugClasses
jarReleaseClasses
transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebugUnitTest
transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForReleaseUnitTest
```

> gradlew   assemble - Assembles all variants of all applications and
>   secondary packages.

Answer (score 6):

The question states that if it is possible to build all flavors using **android studio**. So this might help someone in the future.

Use the **Gradle** option either from the right side toolbar or from 
**View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle** (if gradle is not visible on the toolbar)

Then navigate to **Your Project -> Tasks ->build** click on the desired option as mentioned below to initiate there respective builds

1. **assemble:** assemble both the debug and release versions of all flavors (*Takes a lot of time*)
2. **assembleAndroidTest:** assemble all android unit test
3. **assembleChocolate:** assemble both debug and release version of Chocolate flavor
4. **assembleDebug:** assemble only the debug version of all flavors (*I use this when I do changes which affects all flavors, to make sure all of them build*)
5. **assembleRelease:** assemble only the release version of all flavors.
6. **assembleStrawberry:** assemble both debug and release version of Strawberry flavor
7. **assembleVanila:** assemble both debug and release version of Vanilla flavor

   [image]

kudos :)