# How I can make different apk files in android project?

Tags: android, package, apk

I want create different apk files in one project.

In android studio, I refactor package path, and change manifest package.

and change applicationId, but It still make issue.

When I already installed one and install another apk file which change package name, it asked uninstall before one.

I don't know how to make different apk files which have another package name.

I want install two apk files in one project for test.

Here is my build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.comsol.com_dev.fourslink"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile('com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile('com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.9') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile('gun0912.ted:tedpermission:1.0.2') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile('com.android.support:design:22.+') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile('com.estimote:sdk:0.13.0') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile('jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.0') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile('com.afollestad:easyvideoplayer:0.3.0') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile('com.github.jrvansuita:PickImage:v2.0.0') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile('com.mindorks:placeholderview:0.6.0') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile('com.tsengvn:Typekit:1.0.0') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile('com.github.esafirm:RxDownloader:1.0.1') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile('com.mlsdev.rximagepicker:library:1.1.2') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile('io.github.jeancsanchez.photoviewslider:photoviewslider:1.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'commons-io'
    }
    compile('com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:3.1.0') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile('com.gjiazhe:scrollparallaximageview:1.0') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile('com.droidninja:filepicker:1.0.8') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.11'

    compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.7.1'

    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.7'

    compile 'net.protyposis.android.mediaplayer:mediaplayer:4.3.0'
    compile 'net.protyposis.android.mediaplayer:mediaplayer-dash:4.3.0'

    compile 'com.github.rtoshiro.fullscreenvideoview:fullscreenvideoview:1.1.2'

    compile 'com.github.halilozercan:BetterVideoPlayer:1.1.0'

}
```

and this is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.comsol.com_dev.fourslink">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
        >

        <activity android:name=".Activity.SplashActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

in that, I change comsol to comsec. but overwrite it.

and in strings.xml,

```
<string name="app_name">FoursLink</string>
```

only this, and it change ThreesLink

If you see of that and any idea of it, Please help me.

I don't know why it overwrite it.

Package name is different, it will install other.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44380406/install-two-apks-of-different-versions-of-application/44382198#44382198

Answer (score 0):

In gradle file:

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            applicationId "your.com.dev"
          }

        prod {
            applicationId "your.com.prod"

        }
    }
}
```

Or

Right click in project and open Project Module Settings --> app.

[image]

In command prompt run this command:Assembles all variants of all applications and secondary packages.

```
gradlew  assemble
```

Comment: Yes I did it but still same issue

Comment: Wait issue. Share issue.

Comment: In gradle file, I copy of that and paste it, and view build variants, and select prod and run it but It still show same issue(ask uninstall existing application)

Comment: Hi you can use this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364004/how-to-build-all-product-flavors-from-android-studiothis

Comment: **applicationid** wasn't working when I used it, **applicationIdSuffix** works

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this in `app.gradle`

```
buildTypes {
  release {
    applicationIdSuffix ".release"
  }

  debug {
    applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I copy and paste it, it still same issue